# Removing duplicates from text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, text-files, txt

I have this text file and let's say it contains 10 lines.

```
Bye
Hi
2
3
4
5
Hi
Bye
7
Hi
```

Every time it says `"Hi"` and `"Bye"` I want it to be removed except for the first time it was said.
My current code is (yes filename is actually pointing towards a file, I just didn't place it in this one)

```
text_file = open(filename) 
for i, line in enumerate(text_file):
    if i == 0:
       var_Line1 = line
    if i = 1:
       var_Line2 = line
    if i > 1: 
       if line == var_Line2:
          del line
text_file.close()
```

It does detect the duplicates, but it takes a very long time considering the amount of lines there are, but I'm not sure on how to delete them and save it as well

Comment: Do you want to remove all duplicates or just duplicates of the first 2 lines?

Comment: Mb for the late reply. Yes all duplicates except for the first 2 lines. 
I've gotten it down to remove duplicates from the 2nd line, but the first line has the same info, except for 1 number changing which I want to remove as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dict.fromkeys` to remove duplicates and preserve order efficiently:

```py
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    lines = dict.fromkeys(f.readlines())
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

[Idea from Raymond Hettinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835527/10166393)

Comment: Works good, but how could I get the line number itself? 
1. Hi
2. Bye
3. Bye
How could I know exactly which line got removed? I'd like it to output 3 since it's the duplicated line

Answer (score 1):

Using a set & some basic filtering logic:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    seen = set()  # keep track of the lines already seen
    deduped = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line not in seen:  # if not seen already, write the lines to result
            deduped.append(line)
        seen.add(line)

# re-write the file with the de-duplicated lines
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines([l + '\n' for l in deduped])
```

Comment: Tried this, I'm getting this error
` f.writelines([ l + '\n' for l in deduped]) io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: Make sure your file is not readonly.